# How to detect script file vs executable in custom shell

Tags: c++, shell, unix, cygwin

stackoverflow!  For a systems programming course, I built a custom shell, which I have been tweaking since the end of the assignment for the purpose of hopefully replacing bash and batch as my primary scripting language.  Done in C++ in Cygwin to use unistd.h for piping, forking, etc.  Anyway, one problem I have been running into is that, when running my shell, while executables are recognized as such and run with exec(3) functions, text files (run as scripts) are passed back to bash for execution.  The obvious answer is to put the #! header in every script to redirect to my shell, but I'd like to run my shell as the default when a script is opened inside it.

On a slightly related note, tell me if I should ask this separately, but I'd like to be able to run my shell without starting bash beforehand.  However, I believe Cygwin starts the UNIX environment (necessary for my shell) by running `bash --login -i`
in a batch file.  Is there a possible workaround that doesn't involve running Linux (VM or otherwise)?

Comment: The shebang line (`#!...`) is interpreted by the kernel, not by the shell. I don't think it's optional, or at least leaving it out is not portable. The shell used to interpret a script should never depend on the shell it's being run from.

Comment: the easiest way is to make your shell be called `cygwin\bin\bash.exe` - i.e. replace the default bash with your shell. I'm not au fait with how Cygwin does the `#!` handling, but it may require a custom `cygwin.dll` to override the shell handler when it specifies `/bin/bash`

Comment: My machine uses bash as the default script interpreter.  I realize it's good practice to use shebang all the time, but for the purpose of my shell being the default, could I change the kernel's behavior in this respect to default to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command 'file' can help you to recognize the type of 'file' you want to check

Some examples:

```
$file lavtc.sh
lavtc.sh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines
```

And:

```
$file java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x5cb4cd120c014a335b60544ef209526e8a86f34c, stripped
```

Comment: Hmmm...  I'd probably need to redirect output of an internal `file` command to a variable for parsing...  Would I be correct in assuming that a script file will at least most of the time say "ASCII text"?

Comment: Well, also shell script should do. ... you can also assign directly (without using the file): AVAR=`file myfile.sh` (note the symbol `)

Comment: Well, the idea is to circumvent bash.  `file`, I believe, is an application in the PATH.  If I redirect its output to a cstring, I should be able to parse in my source code.